Knowledge of aboleth tentacle disease
The party is currently on

 The fourth level of the Dungeon of the Mad Mage

and may soon face an aboleth, which they know nothing about in-game.  I have never run one before, but am looking at their tentacle attack:

Tentacle. Melee Weapon Attack: +9 to hit, reach 10 ft., one target. Hit: 12 (2d6 + 5) bludgeoning damage. If the target is a creature, it must succeed on a DC 14 Constitution saving throw or become diseased. The disease has no effect for 1 minute and can be removed by any magic that cures disease. After 1 minute, the diseased creature’s skin becomes translucent and slimy, the creature can’t regain hit points unless it is underwater, and the disease can be removed only by heal or another disease-curing spell of 6th level or higher. When the creature is outside a body of water, it takes 6 (1d12) acid damage every 10 minutes unless moisture is applied to the skin before 10 minutes have passed.

The party includes a war priest with lesser restoration, who could cure the tentacle disease within the first minute, if she knew there was a reason to do so.  They have no access to 6th level magic in the dungeon,

 and it would be extremely difficult to keep a diseased party member wet all the way back up through four dungeon levels to the Yawning Portal.  Most likely they would have to make a short journey to the third level, then leave through the Saurgoth River, exiting the sea caves and approaching Waterdeep from the seaside.

None of the party (which also includes a bear totem barbarian, a shadow elf warlock, and a multiclassed monk / sorcerer, all one long rest away from 8th level) have any abilities that can influence a saving throw as a reaction.
Because this is a monster ability and not a spell, the XGtE rules about Perceiving a caster at work are not directly applicable, but in any event, I do not see any indication that there is a visible effect until it is "too late",

The disease has no effect for 1 minute and can be removed by any magic that cures disease. After 1 minute, the diseased creature’s skin becomes translucent and slimy

It seems like, as written, I would call for a Con save, but regardless of the result, there is no perceivable effect that would prompt the cleric to cure disease.
Is it only after one minute, when lesser restoration can no longer be used, that the character would know something is wrong?

A Medicine or an Arcana check seems appropriate.
Most skills don't give too many examples, but for this both are part of the core rules. Medicine can be used to diagnose an illness, and Arcana can be used for knowledge about the Planes (which would ostensibly include their denizens with a high enough check to beat a CR-based DC).
In this case, where the knowledge or lack thereof clearly has an important consequence for success or failure, if someone was struck with an Aboleth tentacle, it seems appropriate to allow anyone with proficiency in Medicine or Arcana to make a free knowledge check if they see someone struck by the Aboleth or are struck themselves (arguably it might be more appropriate to collect this check before they reach the fight in the first place so you don't tip your hand for those who fail the check that it has something to do with the Aboleth).
If they know they're facing an Aboleth, it seems reasonable that those who pass the check beforehand get that specific info as a heads up and might reasonably share it with the party.
Depending on your group and how you want to run the game and narrative, it may also be appropriate to give an afflicted player narrative details of feelings of malaise...maybe they feel a bit off, they start sweating excessively as their body attempts to keep their skin moisturized... there's a lot of narrative freedom here.
In terms of personal preference, I'd personally lean on as many of these as possible; most of the time you don't get epic feels good stories out of deaths that you had no way to prevent or hinder or even know about within the context of the game.

To be clear - you are suggesting that the check be rolled in advance, before they see the aboleth or perhaps even know they are facing it, and the results of the check only shared once someone makes or fails a tentacle save?

@Kirt If you're trying to preserve the unknown factor for players who don't know the stat block, yes.

Usually it is solved using passive skills, but I do like the roll in advance method.

"most of the time you don't get epic feels good stories out of deaths that you had no way to prevent or hinder or even know about within the context of the game." - I feel this  is an important factor. Worst case the players know perfectly well what's happening and the solution would be easy but they can only sit there and do nothing.

"it may also be appropriate to give an afflicted player narrative details" Strong agree. I think "has no effect" in the rule can easily be read as "has no mechanical effect on rolls or stats etc", not necessarily as "is completely imperceptible". It's ambiguous, and ambiguity is a DM's playground.

@JayMcEh I would welcome that as an answer if you would like to elaborate.

I think this answer already does an excellent job of providing good options for how to communicate the situation with players, I was only emphasizing why it's not a violation of RAW to do so. "No effect" frequently means something different in game terms than in common conversation, so I interpret the rule as leaving space for narrative effects within the first minute like "you notice your skin itching around the wound and are feeling ill", but not mechanical effects like the changes to skin and HP.

@JayMcEh Sorry for the misunderstanding.  We have a policy here to not answer in comments.  While your comments are supportive of TheFallenOne's answer, they are different enough that I (as the querent) would be interested in seeing you write your own answer.

The rules included in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything are an option
In that book, there is a Monster Research section, p. 148, which states (emphasis mine):

Adventurers can research what a creature is likely to desire. The
Monster Research table suggests which skills can be used to learn
about a creature of a particular type. The DC for a relevant ability
check equals 10 + the creature's challenge rating.

Below is the referenced table, and the Suggested Skill could be used to learn about the Aboleth, an Aberration, and the potential disease it can inflict.



Type
Suggested Skills




Aberration
Arcana


Beast
Animal Handling, Nature, or Survival


Celestial
Arcana or Religion


Construct
Arcana


Dragon
Arcana, History, or Nature


Elemental
Arcana or Nature


Fey
Arcana or Nature


Fiend
Arcana or Religion


Giant
History


Humanoid
History


Monstrosity
Nature or Survival


Ooze
Arcana or Survival


Plant
Nature or Survival


Undead
Arcana or Religion




"Research" implies it would need to be done beforehand, though?  So, not knowing they were going to face an aboleth - or even what an aboleth is - there is nothing within the minute after the save was failed that would tell them?

@Kirt "Research" can occasionally be framed as "remembering," although that flows better for some characters than others. It largely depends on the structure of your game. In much the same way that a wizard's hours of self-study that culminates in two new spells every level happens off-screen, perhaps while the neophyte life cleric was learning the finer points of lesser restoration from a senior clergy member, they told an old story about their adventuring days where a fellow adventurer almost dried up to death. Skill check to see if the Aboleth triggers the memory after it hits someone.

Sorry @Kirt, I didn't see your comment until now. I see this rule from TCoE as a way for characters to learn about creatures they're facing. It's a tool for DMs to give players more insight into creatures. How much they learn might also depend on the roll.


The disease has no effect for 1 minute and can be removed by any magic that cures disease.

It is true, that does not mandate you to have a visible effect.  Or you could read it as having no mechanical effect.
Which of these lead to a good in-game result, from your perspective?
...
When faced with a new monster (to the players), I'd start with a knowledge check of DC (10+monster CR).  Players who succeed get information about the monster from in-game past knowledge.  For an Aberration, Arcana is a good skill to ask for.
Failing that, I'd give characters who fail the Con save minor symptoms.  Their skin feels slimy and they get a rash.  These symptoms increase in intensity after the fight.
Players who look at the rash can make a Medicine check (I'd go with DC 10) to notice that the flesh seems to be infected with something (they don't know what, unless they hit a 20+ on the Medicine check).
Solving this problem is a minor puzzle.  For a minor puzzle, you want to give at least 3 independent clues for the solution (lesser restoration, right away, is the solution).

The Arcana check is possible clue.
The itchy rash is a possible clue.
The medicine check is a possible clue.

Here, 3 relies on 2 - so I might also include a separate clue.  In this case, have transparent sections of skin on some of the aboleth's slaves.
Now, this is a puzzle-first option.
Another option is combat-as-war.  PCs who don't actively make knowledge checks and research their foes?  Oh well, you didn't know, your character is screwed.  Do better next time!
A third path exists if you don't want to play the puzzle game at all.  Just tell the player they need lessor restoration.
Which of these three paths you take should depend on what kind of D&D game you want to play.  All 3 would be fun at some tables, and rather suck at other tables.

Good advice that how this plays out should depend on the playstyle expected at the table.  You might ground the statement that "For an Aberration, Arcana is a good skill to ask for." by citing the TCoE rules, as Tarod does in their answer

There's also the simple expedient of giving the PCs a warning via the narrative that aboleths can make you terminally slimy, which may lead them to trying to cure the disease quickly.  They could encounter the diary of the last survivor of a group who was wiped out, planning notes from Blackcloak, or maybe an identifiable if dodgy herbal preparation for curing skin conditions with "apolef" written on the stained label.
